# I can't move most of the armature bones

Tags: armature

I downloaded a free rigged model, and in pose mode, most of the bones are completely frozen and cannot be moved. I can move the hand, and that moves the arm with it, but I can't rotate the hand or fingers. This is the same with everybody part except the face rig.

Comment: You should rig it yourself unless you want to pay for a model. I don't always trust free models.

Comment: i was thinking of deleting it, but the rig is very complex, and i could never make something like that myself.